# How can I use translateY to successive display elements one a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ultimately, for each click of a button, I want to display an element that contains new content. In other words...

- You read content contained within a parent container
- To see the next item click the button
- When the button is clicked, the old content shifts downward. The new content flows down from the top of the container. It pauses in order to read the new content.
- To get new content, press the button again.

I'm unclear as to how to accomplish this, and if it's even possible with a `CSS` Animation. With what I have posted, it just takes both elements and translates them down the vertical axis at once. How can this be refactored so that one element pauses and displays it's content ***using just `vanilla JavaScript`***?

```js
var div1 = document.querySelector(".first");
var div2 = document.querySelector(".second");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

var divs = [div1, div2];

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  for (var i = divs.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    var div = divs[i];
    div.classList.remove("down_shift");
    void div.offsetWidth;
    div.classList.add("down_shift");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

section {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first, .second {
  width: inherit;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-300px);
}

.second {
  background: pink;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.down_shift {
  animation: down 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes down{
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="first"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="second"><h1>2</h1></div>
</section>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: What animation do you use to fade out, and what one are you using to fade in?

Comment: The only animation I have is listed in the CSS. I'm not sure of the flow required for the desired outcome given I've never attempted this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a wrapper to the elements, and animate the wrapper

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var button = document.querySelector("button");


button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  wrapper.style.transform = 'translateY(-300px)'
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

section {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first, .second {
  width: inherit;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
   /* transform: translateY(-300px); */
}

.second {
  background: pink;
}

.wrapper {
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}




.down_shift {
  animation: down 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes down{
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="second"><h1>2</h1></div>
  </div>
</section>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```